# When is an Erratum needed?

Tags: errors-erratum

A typo, a spelling error etc., in a published paper is definitely not enough for issuing an erratum.
If a mistake destroys a main result, then an erratum is definitely necessary.
What about cases in between? What about a typo mistake in expressing a value which does not affect the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the field and the nature of the error. It is a judgement call. If a reader is likely to be misled in some way, even if not about the main result then a correction is warranted - or at least serious consideration of a correction.

For example, in mathematics, the proof of a theorem is fairly often more important than the theorem itself. This is the case if it gives insight into the solution of other (important) questions. So, an error in a proof might require an explicit correction if the error would mislead readers and give the wrong/incorrect "insight". But one needs to use judgement about the nature and effect of the error, even beyond the specific result (theorem).

This likely extends to other fields as well, though, perhaps, in different ways.

But, literally, a typo in a value seems less likely to rise to the level that a correction is essential. Little harm in making it right, though.